# Animated element deletion HTML CSS JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

please tell me how to make an activity, when you press red square, the red square is removed, and the green one slowly decreases, my code doesn't work

```js
function del() {
        document.getElementById("del").style = "display:none";
    }
```

```css
.container {
        width: 30vmin;
        background: green;
        transition: all 5s ease;
    }

    #del {
        width: 10vmin;
        height: 10vmin;
        background: red;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="del" onclick="del()"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: display: none does not work with transition

Comment: Please note that `display` differs from `opacity` or `width`/`height`! `display` isn't affected by transitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two related factors here:

- the container only has height because its child (the red square) has
  height so when you make that 0vmin the green div also disappears as
  it now has no content with height - this is not the same as setting its
  style.height to 0

  on clicking the red square it disappears immediately as required but
  nothing is done about the container

This snippet adds two things: it gives a specific initial height to the container and it sets the container's opacity to 0 when the red square is clicked. Obviously you can change the effects you want (is it to go slowly smaller rather than slowly disappear for example?):

```js
function del() {
        document.getElementById("del").style = "display:none";
        document.querySelector(".container").style.opacity = '0';
    }
```

```css
.container {
        width: 30vmin;
        background: green;
        transition: all 5s ease;
        height: 10vmin;
    }

    #del {
        width: 10vmin;
        height: 10vmin;
        background: red;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="del" onclick="del()"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Display: none can't be used with transitions. Try opacity

Also when your red box is removed from the UI, your .container has no height set and seems to disappear as well. In reality it's still there but just has 0 height

Answer (score -1):

[`display: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) isn't affected by transitions: an element is either displayed or not. There are two properties that are affected by transitions that might interest you:

- [`opacity: 0;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)
- [`width: 0;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)

`opacity` is similar to `display: hidden;` but can range from `0.0` to `1.0` (from `0%` to `100%`).

`width` simply "hides horizontally" the element (it removes a dimension).

I suggest to use classes instead of ids and switch to the one that "deletes" the element (actually hides it).

```js
function del() {
  const delEl = document.getElementById("del");
  delEl.style = "display:none";
  const containerEl = document.getElementById("container");
  containerEl.style = "width: 20vmin";
}
```

```css
#container {
  height: 10vmin;
  width: 30vmin;
  background: green;
  transition: all 5s ease;
}

#del {
  height: 10vmin;
  width: 10vmin;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="del" onclick="del()"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The OP states he want to remove the red query and slowly decreases the green square. Your green square remains while the red one decreases (width) slowly.

Comment: Thank you I completely missed the question. Probably I got confused while reading a previous edit. I fixed my code now!

Answer (score -1):

You need to set an opacity to the container element to use the transition and set a height to it so it doesn't lose the height when the `#del` element is removed. To make it easier I created an javascript event handler instead of your inline event handler.

```js
document.querySelector('#del').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.currentTarget.style = "display:none";
  e.currentTarget.parentElement.style = "opacity:0";
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 30vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
  background: green;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 5s ease;
}

#del {
  width: 10vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="del"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't use `querySelector` just for ids, it's way slower than `getElementById`!

Comment: @DadiBit I like to use query selector for readability so I can write my selectors in a uniform way. You won't notice the performance difference unless you do some very large iterations, which is not likely on client side code. It's a matter of personal preference of course but a tiny performance boost is not always worth it in my opinion.

Comment: @DadiBit https://jsfiddle.net/xf3z0swo/1/ As you can see in the jsfiddle, even with 1 million iterations the difference is only about 150-200 ms (my computer in latest chrome). Most people won't even notice this. If you have performance issues then it's unlikely that it is caused by this.